# Image denoising filter based on an over-smoothed estimate

Tags: image, filtering, noise

I want to denoise an image affected by Gaussian White Noise, with knwon standard deviation. I've constructed an estimate of the clean signal using patches from a library of clean images. I want to use this estimate to form a filter, to filter the original noisy image, hopefully retaining more detail while removing the noise.

I've tried wiener filtering in the fourier domain, and in the wavelet domain, based on the statistics of the over-smoothed estimate, but the results are less accurate than the over-smoothed estimate.

Is there a standard way to form a filter for image denoising based on an estimate of the clean signal?